# how can i send a lot of data to a database using stored procedure?

Tags: .net, sql, t-sql

I need to send a lot of data from the server(using c#) to the database at once, for example all the data are in a 'csv' format and i need to pass it once to the database.. the database functionality is implemented in the database,I mean i'm using the stored procedure way(T-SQL)...

I tried to use the 'bulk insert' way and it works... but unfortunately it only works with a file... I don't need to use a file, i need to pass it in another way, like a string or anyway but not file...

how i can do that ??

this is the site for the 'bulk insert'
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

thanks alot...

Comment: what exactly you mean when you say database functionality is implemented in the database ??

Comment: He says he uses a stored procedure. So it seems he wants to bulk-send from ASP.NET to a stored procedure.

Comment: I meant,that i'm using the stored procedure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do using Table-Valued Parameters. Please find more details at below mentioned link.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

Hope it will help for you.

Comment: yes... what about the SQL 2005 ?? does these features also available in 2005 ?? and, Thanks alot ;)

Comment: Table-Valued Parameters not working with SQL Server 2005, i think for sql server 2005 use should use xml.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create xml and send that to a sp that interprets the xml.

[improving ms sql insert performance with lazarus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756851/improving-ms-sql-insert-performance-with-lazarus/4757059#4757059)

**Edit 1** Add sample code

Create a test table

```
create table TestTable (Id int, Name nvarchar(50))
```

Create the stored procedure that insert from xml to table

```
create procedure XMLInsertToTestTable
    @Data xml
as
insert into TestTable (Id, Name)
select
    r.r.value('Id[1]', 'int'),
    r.r.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(50)')
from @Data.nodes('root/row') r(r)
```

Call the procedure with xml-string as argument

```
exec XMLInsertToTestTable
  '<root>
    <row> 
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Name>Name 1</Name>
    </row>    
    <row> 
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Name>Name 2</Name>
    </row>    
  </root>'
```

Comment: unfortunately "Mikael Eriksson", even with the xml i have to use a file way... I want to avoid the file way... Is that possible ?? thanks a lot "Mikael Eriksson"

Comment: Wouldn't using XML here affect performance given that XML has to be parsed...etc
Any more efficient way, perhaps?

Comment: @Voulnet, Yes it has to be parsed. I think XML is not as fast as bcp but it is a lot faster than adding one row at a time. Only way to know for sure is to do some testing yourself.

Comment: @Q8Y, why/where do you need a file when passing xml to a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options

1. SQL Export Import Wizard
2. using bcp utility programmatically
   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx